# Canvas collision

Tags: javascript, canvas, 2d-games

I programmed canvas collision into my html game. I have checked numerous times but I cant find a problem with the code.

```
// Handle left and right collisions with the canvas
if (player.x <= canvas.x) {
    // Left edige
    player.xdir = 1;
    player.x = canvas.x;
} else if (player.x + player.width >= canvas.x + canvas.width) {
    // Right edge
    player.xdir = -1;
    player.x = canvas.x + canvas.width - player.width;
}

// Handle top and bottom collisions with the canvas
if (player.y <= canvas.y) {
    // Top edge
    player.ydir = 1;
    player.y = canvas.y;
} else if (player.y + player.height >= canvas.y + canvas.height) {
    // Bottom edge
    player.ydir = -1;
    player.y = canvas.y + canvas.height - player.height;
}
```

Comment: "I cant find a problem with the code" <-- but I assume you have some issues with your code, otherwise you wouldn't post it on StackOverflow. What's the matter?

Comment: What is canvas.x?

Comment: I need fresh eyes @le_m

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the `canvas.x` thing is misunderstood. Everything in canvas is always absolute relative to the canvas' point of origin:

```js
//Polyfill for "requestAnimationFrame"
window.requestAnimationFrame = window.requestAnimationFrame ||
  window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
  window.mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
  window.msRequestAnimationFrame ||
  function(callback) {
    setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
  };
//The player object
var player = {
  x: 50,
  y: 150,
  xdir: 1,
  ydir: 1,
  width: 10,
  height: 10
};
//The canvas (creation and appending)
var canvas = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("canvas"));
canvas.height = 200;
canvas.width = canvas.height;
//Rendering context
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

function simulate() {
  //Move player
  if (player.xdir === 1) {
    player.x += 1;
  } else {
    player.x -= 1;
  }
  if (player.ydir === 1) {
    player.y += 1;
  } else {
    player.y -= 1;
  }
  // Handle left and right collisions with the canvas
  if (player.x <= player.width * 0.5) {
    // Left edige
    player.xdir = 1;
  } else if (player.x + player.width >= canvas.width + player.width * 0.5) {
    // Right edge
    player.xdir = -1;
  }
  // Handle top and bottom collisions with the canvas
  if (player.y <= player.height * 0.5) {
    // Top edge
    player.ydir = 1;
  } else if (player.y + player.height >= canvas.height + player.height * 0.5) {
    // Bottom edge
    player.ydir = -1;
  }
  requestAnimationFrame(simulate);
  //Draw the player (just for fun)
  ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(235,235,255,0.1)";
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  ctx.fillStyle = "red";
  ctx.fillRect(player.x - 0.5 * player.width, player.y - 0.5 * player.height, player.width, player.height);
}
//Start simulation
simulate();
```

```css
canvas {
  background-color: rgba(235, 235, 255, 0.1);
}
```

Comment: So we create the detection using the player's height in reference to the canvas.

Comment: @Teazzy1 That's my guess. I don't see the point in tracking the canvas position, unless you have a variable called canvas that's tracking the view port location.

Comment: Worth a +1 if you used `requestAnimationFrame` rather than `setTimeout`